# Export to csv in ui-grid : exporterAllDataFn fires only when we have more than one page

Tags: javascript, web, angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

exporterAllDataFn event fires only when we have more than one page : when i reduce the page size and i have two pages it fires but when i have only one page it doesn't fire.i have some code in exporterAllDataFn that must be run each time . is there any solution or other way to run some piece of code before exporting ?!!

Answer (score 0):

you can use it to call a new function which you can handle the downloading of CSV:

exporterAllDataFn: function () {

```
                $scope.downloadCSV();
```

}

and handled the csv here:

```
$scope.downloadCSV = function () {


            paramsObj['query'] = $scope.keyword;

            $scope.downloadCSVPromise = Material.query(paramsObj, function (response) {

                if (response && response.partSearchList && response.partSearchList.length > 0) {

                    $scope.noData = false;

                    $scope.numFound = response.numFound;

                    **var csv = JSON2CSV(response.partSearchList);**
                    //window.open("data:text/csv;charset=utf-8," + escape(csv))

                    if (window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
                        var blob_ie = new Blob([decodeURIComponent(encodeURI(csv))], {
                            type: "text/csv;charset=utf-8;"
                        });
                        navigator.msSaveBlob(blob_ie, 'FileName.csv');
                    }

                    var date = new Date();
                    var today = date.toString().substr(4,20);
                    var regex = new RegExp(" ", 'g');
                    today = today.replace(regex, '_');
                    var fileNm = 'AGSExtract_'+today+'.csv';

                    var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
                    var blob = new Blob(["\ufeff", csv]);
                    var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                    downloadLink.href = url;
                    downloadLink.download = fileNm;

                    document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
                    downloadLink.click();
                    document.body.removeChild(downloadLink);

                } else {

                    $scope.noData = true;
                }
            });

        };
```

Above solution is for server side full data, if you are using client side pagination then check for JSON2CSV and pass the $scope variable which has the table data.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: my problem is that exporterAllDataFn code does not even fire when we have one page

Comment: Can you make a plunker or jsfiddle to show your code then may be i could help because i have implemented the same and works smooth silk.